# load a new page automatically accessing only an element in the body

Tags: javascript, load

Is there any way to load a new different page without user interaction when I have access only to the body of the page and not to head?

For example, the following code fails:

```
<a href="javascript:function(){window.open('http://www.google.com','_self')}();">open google home page</a>
```

(I want that www.google.com is loaded as soon as the current page is loaded without any user click on any one of its elements)

No jQuery, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just insert a script element into the page like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `function()`. It should be:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="autoopen" onclick="return false;">open google home page</a>
```

```
<script type="type/javascript">
for (var i = 0; i < document.anchors.length; i++)
{
  var a = document.anchors[i];
  if (a.rel == "autoopen")
  {
    window.open(a.href, '_self');
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just before closeing body tag put

```
<script>
 location.href = "http://www.google.com";
</script>
```